# #LinkedIn LinkedIn's OpenGraph scraper not accepting SSL certificates released by Letsencrypt

Tags: https, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, lets-encrypt

To the LinkedIn API support team

I'm using free SSL certificates released by letsencrypt dot org, the new open certification authority.
Linkedin's bot fails to scrape OpenGraph tags on my blog, because of an SSL issue on the client side (the certificate is unknown for the client, Linkedin scraper doesn't trust it), so I can't actually share my contents with proper OpenGraph parsing.
What I see from the nginx logs is:
SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094416:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate unknown:SSL alert number 46) while SSL handshaking.
Other opengraph-enabled social sites work as expected.

Could you please take a look at this?

Thank you!

Comment: #Linkedin
LinkedIn developers, could you please look at this?

Comment: LinkedIn has to trust SSL root CA, this is not the right place for asking LinkedIn to review their bot.

Comment: Linkedin uses stack overflow for tech support for their APIs.
I asked here after having contacted them through their ticket system, because they told me to.
However the problem got solved a few months ago

Comment: I do not believe it has been solved. Posts I share with a Let's Encrypt cert are not properly accepted, while posts I share with a low-end Comodo cert do just fine.

Comment: Mine are working fine, the scraper is able to parse them as well... could you look at the webserver's logs while running the linkedin's opengraph scraper?

Comment: For me it showed an error because we enforced TLS1.3, which seems not to work with the LinkedIn Bot, going to a lower version solved it.